# Text searching issue in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been using Powershell successfully searching through .txt files for various strings, but have run into a quandary.   I want to search within a .txt file for the existence of three different strings.

The three similar strings that I am looking for are the following.

"Option I"
"Option II"
"Option III"

The file can contain any combination of these strings.  That is, the file may contain all three text strings or two of the three etc...

The problem I'm having is when searching for the "Option I" string, it is finding that sub-string within "Option II" and "Option III", or searching for "Option II" it is being found within the "Option III" string.

These strings happen to all end with a CR/LF, but it seems that the CR/LF are being stripped off before the search can take place. I was trying to search for `` Option I`r`n `` with no luck.

I have been using

`Select-String -Pattern "Option I"`

Answer (score 0):

To indicate that "I" should be the end, use "\W", and "$" for end-of-line:

```
Select-String -Pattern "Option I(\W|$)"
```

And this might interest you too:

```
Select-String -Pattern "Option I{1,3}(\W|$)"
```

3 flies in one hit

With this file, test.txt:

```
There is no Option 1 here on this line
There is an Option I here on this line
There is an Option II here on this line
There is at the end of this line, an Option I
Are you looking for an Option III on this line?
There is an Option IV here on this line
```

executing

```
Select-String -Pattern "Option I{1,3}(\W|$)"  test.txt
```

gives:

```
test.txt:2:There is an Option I here on this line
test.txt:3:There is an Option II here on this line
test.txt:4:There is at the end of this line, an Option I
test.txt:5:Are you looking for an Option III on this line?
```

Comment: I tried making the \W work.  It does not match any pattern the way it is posted.  I changed to single quotes Select-String -Path "$FILE" -Pattern 'Option I\w'  it kinda-sort of matched, but striped the last "I"  weird behavior.  I'll need to do more reading/experimenting.

Comment: I forgot to take the end-of-line into account.  Corrected my answer.

Comment: This works, assuming that the strings shouldn't just be matched at the _end_ of a line, but note that `(\W|$)` can be simplified to word-boundary assertion `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

> These strings happen to all end with a CR/LF, but it seems that the CR/LF are being stripped off before the search can take place.

`Select-String` searches the lines of a given input file *one by one*, with each line indeed having its trailing newline (CRLF) *stripped*.

Therefore, instead of trying to match CRLF (which isn't there), match the *end of the input* using  regex anchor `$`; e.g.:

```
# Create sample input file.
@'
Option I
Option II
Option III
'@ > tmp.txt

# Search the file for 'Option I' at the end of each line.
Select-String 'Option I$' tmp.txt
```

The above yields:

```
       
tmp.txt:1:Option I
```

That is, thanks to anchoring the search regex at the end of the line (`$`), only the line ending in `Option I` matched.

If you also wanted to match occurrences not just at the end of the line, but you want to make sure those matches occur at *word boundaries*, use `\b`:

```
Select-String 'Option I\b' tmp.txt
```

Use `'\bOption I\b'` to also ensure that the start of the search string occurs at a word boundary.

Also note that `Select-String` is case-*insensitive* by default; use `-CaseSensitive` to change that.